# Selecting adjacent parcels with similar attributes in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am working on a project that is trying to identify shared ownership of adjacent parcels on abandoned industrial lands. I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2 and ModelBuilder right now. The first parts of my model work fine where I select parcels of a particular industrial type and I've dropped a 500m buffer on parcels to grab surrounding parcels. I now would like to select parcels that have the same property owner.

This is all working on a single layer right now. Is there a tool that allows me to check parcel attributes against themselves and return only adjacent parcels with shared ownership?

Comment: Well, you would use Select By Attributes on a new Feature Layer and select those parcels that have the value = value of the owner from the selected feature, i.e. parcel.

Comment: I've tried that but it just gives me the same feature layer. I was thinking this may require something more akin to a self-join. Or would you know a better WHERE clause to make the correction?

Comment: If same owner parcels intersect, it is enough to Dissolve them (NO MULTIPARTS option) using owner field as case. If they are separated, you'll need script. Yes one of the steps will be spatial join to itself. Let me know if you are Ok with script, I'll post an answer

Comment: If you are interested in technically adjacent rather than just nearby parcels you may want to consider the Polygon Neighbors tool.  That coupled with an ArcPy cursor would be a reasonably straightforward solution.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. I had to go a series of meetings but I will try these suggestions tomorrow. Thank you.